# Remove or change [c++]

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [c++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) has become ambiguous and a [source of confusion](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3745/is-it-safe-to-assume-c11-by-now-even-if-the-question-is-not-tagged-as-such). There is [c++98](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98) (not used), [c++03](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03), [c++11](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), [c++14](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), soonish there will be [c++17](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) and [c++22](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b22) and then there is [c++0x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x) (synonym for [c++11](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)) and [c++1y](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1y) (which should be a synonym for [c++17](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)). C++11 is so much different from C++03 that most answers for one tend to be wrong or not very useful for the other.

One way to deal with this is to make [c++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) a union of all other C++ tags which should be reflected in the description and when searching for C++ questions. Additionally C++ should not be a valid tag for new questions.

Another way would be to treat the different versions of C++ as different languages and remove [c++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) altogether.

There may be similar issues with other languages such as Java 5/6/7/8 and C 89,98,11.

Comment: I think this will make it harder for [tag:c++] experts to follow all [tag:c++] questions.

Comment: @skiwi Unless you make following [tag:c++] equivalent to following [tag:c++98] [tag:c++03] [tag:c++11] and [tag:c++14].

Comment: actually SE allows to favorite wildcard-tags, which is awesome... Anyways, we had that discussion about java already. IIRC the final resolution was "no multiple java tags, but for languages where there's no backwards compatibility guaranteed keep a 'root tag' and the specific version tags"

Comment: We could do what we did with Java, and have the C++ standard tags a synonym of [tag:c++].  Otherwise, knowing which standard tag to use for sure could be more confusing.

Comment: Once again we need tag hierarhies, and once again it is in order to solve the problem of programming languages versionning.